# Trying to install a perl module with cpanm, got a fail

Tags: powershell, perl, module

So I just installed Strawberry Perl and now I want to get the following module:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::CMUDict
So I typed in "cpanm Lingua::EN::CMUDict" and got:
[image: x]

So I tried again with "cpanm Lingua::EN::CMUDict --force" and got the same exact thing.
Here are the contents of the log in question:

cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7044 on perl 5.032001 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
Work directory is C:\Users\matth/.cpanm/work/1630544096.16456
You have make C:\Users\c\bin\gmake.exe
You have LWP 6.52
Falling back to Archive::Tar 2.38

==============

Tried verbose output, got this:

```
--> Working on Lingua::EN::CMUDict
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/L/LM/LMETCALF/Lingua-EN-CMUDict-0.06.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Lingua-EN-CMUDict-0.06 ... OK
Building and testing Lingua-EN-CMUDict-0.06 ... FAIL
! Installing Lingua::EN::CMUDict failed. See C:\Users\matth\.cpanm\work\1630595312.29316\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Finding Write-Verbose on cpanmetadb failed.
! Finding Write-Verbose () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Write-Verbose
```

And that log:
https://pastebin.com/iSS5LRKA

Also, it says my File::ShareDir is up to date.

I have installed the file manually, and put it in perl\lib, but it says it doesn't exist. Where should I put it?

Comment: I tried to install this on Windows 10, Strawberry Perl 5.32, now and it installed fine here. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Xi763RQL) is the install log. Can you try to run `cpanm` with the verbose flag to get more information?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. It makes no sense. Posting text as text is far more useful to anyone trying to help you.

Comment: The [log file](https://pastebin.com/iSS5LRKA) shows that there is a permission error : `ERROR: Can't create 'C:\Users\perl\site\lib\Lingua\EN'
mkdir C:\Users\perl\site\lib\Lingua: Permission denied; Access is denied`. Can you check if you have write permissions to `C:\Users\perl\site` ?

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the module in CPAN and under Kwalitee issues I found:

```
prereq_matches_use
    List all used modules in META.yml requires
    Error:
        File::ShareDir
```

When I downloaded (but not installed) the module I found this in the code
(in Lingua/EN/CMUDict.pm): `use File::ShareDir ':ALL'`

So maybe the installation is missing this module and you could try to install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It was Håkon Hægland that helped. As soon as I changed the permission to lib, it worked.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the necessary information. Or ask Håkon Hægland to convert his comment to an answer.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.